# Combine WITH AS and JOIN in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

For some reason, in presto sql, I cannot use "WITH table_name AS (... JOIN ...)". For instance:

```sql
WITH table_name AS 

    (SELECT att1 FROM table1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    
    SELECT att2 FROM table2

    ON att1=att2)

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_name
```

Gives syntax error. I've tried many combinations, unsuccessfully. I have no idea if it is common to most sql engines or just presto. Would anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off.  It should be:

```sql
WITH table_name AS (
    SELECT t1.att1, t2.att2
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.att1 = t2.att2
)

SELECT *
FROM table_name;
```

A single query/subquery should have only one `SELECT` clause.  In addition, I have added table *aliases* to the query to make it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that, but with "SELECT att1 FROM table1" instead of just table1 (and same for table2). I wonder why this does not work.

Comment: @Archimondain "does not work" is not very useful. How exactly it does not work?

Comment: Nevermind, I must have got mixed up, I can't reproduce it.